# Using LGD (Loss Given Default) in the trading of bonds

Tags: fixed-income, trading, risk-management, credit, quants

Do you use the LGD as a risk management tool when trading credit cash bonds? Or it's more for trading the loan product.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with using LGD is that unless the bond issuer is on the verge of default, you don't have a good estimate of what the defaulted bond would be worth. Sometimes it is not clear even for some time after a default. Some regulations may insist that you guess for Current Expected Credit Loss (CECL) and for IFRS 9 expected credit loss and impairment analysis, but if a default occurs, anyone's guess is unlikely to turn out to be even close. With that in mind:

It's pretty common for credit trading desks to report at least two "jump to default" risk measures - one using zero recovery (i.e. 100% LGD; the most conservative if you're just long some bonds) and also one using the some recovery assumption (more meaningful if you have some bonds, CDSs, and other credit products). More comprehensively, you can have a grid of the P&L impact if the credit defaults and the recovery is 90%, 80%.... 10%, 0%.

Estimating the P&L from a credit event with recovery $R$ is fast and straightforward for vanilla products. For a bond or a loan, the P&L is $R-$ the dirty price. For a vanilla credit defaut swap, the protection buyer's P&L is $-pv - R + \textrm{notional}$, where $pv$ is the mark to market. For a credit defaut swap with fixed recovery $F$, it is $-pv - F + \textrm{notional}$, does not depend on $R$.

The risk measure gets a little complicated for things like (options om) $n$th to default baskets, but few people trade those anymore.

For products marked to model using a recovery assumption, such as CDSs, it is also common to calculate a "recovery assumption 01" - sometimes with a term structure - showing the sensitivity to changes in the recovery assumption. For products with observable price, such as bonds, this risk measure is not very useful except to see how well the bonds' recovery01 hedges the CDS's recovery01, so some people calculate it for bonds for this reason.

Not a risk measure, but sometimes it is also useful to calculate the probability of default (and CDS spread) implied by a bond's price and some LGD assumption. You'd also need this calculation for a bond recovery01.